# logstash prune plugin causes json to become text (/ruby objects)

Tags: logstash

I'm using logstash that outputs to coralogix. It works fine, unless i use the prune plugin to whitelist fields. once i use the prune plugin, it outputs text/string instead of a json object.

the used code:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5000
  }
}

filter {
  if [should_prune] {
    prune {
      whitelist_names => [
        "^test$",
        "^@timestamp$",
        "^tags$"
        ]
     }
     add_tag => [ "pruned" ]
  }
}

output {
    coralogix_logger {
      config_params => {
        "PRIVATE_KEY" => "********"
        "APP_NAME" => "myawesomeapp"
        "SUB_SYSTEM" => "subapp"
      }
      is_json => true
    }
}
```

example of output is:

```
{"@timestamp"=>2019-07-15T06:47:57.364Z, "tags"=>["pruned"], "test"=>"ok"}
```

instead of:

```
{"@timestamp":2019-07-15T06:47:57.364Z, "tags":["pruned"], "test":"ok"}
```

any logs that are not pruned (in this scenario, doesn't contain the `should_prune` field), are passed just fine.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my issues was not related to the prune plugin, it was related to the plugin I used to output my logs (in my case - coralogix). had to update my output plugin (https://github.com/coralogix/logstash-output-coralogix).

if you encounter this issue and not using coralogix, another method to resolve this can be using the "json_encode" plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json_encode.html

generally speaking, it should work out of the box - just like the configuration i used in the initial question.